# Kali Linux Live Boot USB Persistence using Command Prompt

Tags: kali-linux, persistence

I currently have Kali Linux Live Boot on my USB, but I'd like to make it persistent. All the websites I have visited uses an application that is not included in Windows.

Is there a way I can create persistence using in-built tools such as Diskpart or Disk Management?

Comment: If you did not edit/remove any file it will be persistent for long time.

Comment: @Biswa I created a folder on the desktop, rebooted and the folder disappeared.

Comment: Do you want to add folders and files in that Linux live image?

Comment: I don't know which imaging-tool do you use, perhaps you could create an extra volume before copying the iso to the usb-drive. Here an example:  http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

Comment: @Biswa Yes, and also changes in apps such as extensions in Firefox to be persistent.

Comment: @GaiRui I'm using CommandLineDiskImager: https://github.com/davidferguson/CommandLineDiskImager. I've seen that website, but I was looking for a way to do it in Windows.